# Spark Structured Streaming with Avro deserialization: NullPointerException while trying to read the message

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to read Avro data using Spark Structured Streaming and Kafka. The code I am using is the following:

```
package com.test.spark

import com.test.spark.ConfigKafka.getAvroSchema
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, Encoder, SparkSession}

object AvroConsumer extends App {

  val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .getOrCreate()

  val sparkContext: SparkContext = sparkSession
    .sparkContext
  sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

  private val topic: String = "topic-test"
  private val queryName: String = "TEST_QUERY"

  private val autoOffsetReset: String = "earliest"

  val avroReader: GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord] = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](getAvroSchema(topic))
  val avroDecoderFactory: DecoderFactory = DecoderFactory.get()
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[GenericRecord] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[GenericRecord]

  import sparkSession.implicits._

  val kafkaDataFrame: DataFrame = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("subscribe", topic)
    .option("group.id", queryName)
    .option("startingOffsets", autoOffsetReset)
    .options(ConfigKafka.getSparkConsumerProperties())
    .load()

  val data: Dataset[String] = kafkaDataFrame
    .select(col("value").as[Array[Byte]])
    .map(d => {
      val rec: GenericRecord = avroReader.read(null, avroDecoderFactory.binaryDecoder(d, null))
      val idContract: String = rec.get("idContract").asInstanceOf[org.apache.avro.util.Utf8].toString
      println(s"idContract = $idContract")
      idContract
    })

  data
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", false)
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()

}
```

in the `ConfigKafka` object, I manage all the connection and the retrieval of the Avro schema to the schema registry:

```
object ConfigKafka {

  def getConfMap(): Map[String, String] = {
    Map(AbrisConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL -> schemaRegistryUrl,
      SchemaRegistryClientConfig.USER_INFO_CONFIG -> s"${userAccount}:${Encoder.decode(userPassword)}",
      SchemaRegistryClientConfig.BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE -> "USER_INFO")
  }

  def getAvroSchema(inputTopic: String): Schema = {
    val subjectName: String = s"$inputTopic-value"
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    val confMap: Map[String, String] = getConfMap()
    val schemaRegistryClient: CachedSchemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 128, confMap.asJava)
    val stringSchema: String = schemaRegistryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(subjectName).getSchema
    new Schema.Parser().parse(stringSchema)
  }

}
```

The Avro schema of the messages I'm trying to read is:

```
{
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Contract",
 "namespace": "com.test.data.contract", 
 "fields": [
  {
    "default": null,
    "name": "entity",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ]
  },
  {
    "default": null,
    "name": "idContract",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ]
  },
  {
    "default": null,
    "name": "codeContract",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

At first, my goal is to read the `idContract` field but I get a `NullPointerException` error:

```
23/05/19 11:16:46 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
23/05/19 11:16:46 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@5f3442ad is aborting.
23/05/19 11:16:46 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@5f3442ad aborted.
23/05/19 11:16:46 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = c3424864-6f80-4c29-a316-50949782af69, runId = b4964f51-400b-44a4-8cbc-dc6a16a3922e] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (host.fr executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.spark.AvroConsumer$.$anonfun$data$1(AvroConsumer.scala:41)
```

The error points the following line of my code:

```
val rec: GenericRecord = avroReader.read(null, avroDecoderFactory.binaryDecoder(d, null))
```

How can I deserialize the value properly?

Comment: Avro requires a schema to deserialize. You cannot pass null as schema parameter. But how was the Avro data produced? Are you needing to use a schema registry?

Comment: I use an Avro schema by querying the schema registry with the `getAvroSchema(topic)` method. I also tested the access to the registry and this one is OK.

Comment: Your code never uses that schema though during the binary decoder call

Comment: Also see https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Comment: Confluent Avro payloads aren't encoded the way that binary decoder expects anyway. I suggest you use the above library to simplify your code

Comment: I am familiar with the Abris library which I use often. However, I am working on a message that has several levels of nesting in its structure. I need to retrieve attributes that are positioned at the fifth level of the structural tree of the message. With Abris, if I want to retrieve such attributes, I will have to flatten the message (with the `explode()` function), which I try to avoid. So I'm looking to exploit the Avro API so as not to break the structure of the event in order to retrieve these attributes. I'm trying to retrieve fields that are positioned at the root of the message.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explode anything. You should be able to run this in SparkSQL `select('value.obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.*')`. Regardless, as mentioned `BinaryDecoder` will not work with Confluent-encoded Avro format without stripping out the first 5 bytes from the value, anyway